# Java Concurrency based on condition

Tags: java, multithreading

Create a method which accept a integer as a argument and print on console. This method is accessed by multiple threads. If two or more threads call the method with same value then only one thread should allow to print the value other threads should wait. If values are different then all threads should allow to print the value.
I know interning would help here but Java interning happens till values less than 128. After that two Integer having same value are different object... Can it be done? Any provision for synchronizing on condition??

Comment: '..other thread should wait' until what?

Comment: you don't synchronize on a *condition* - you synchronize on an object, and then (in your case) do logic within the synchronized block based on the value of that object, depending on whether it meets a condition. But this whole question is very ill-defined. For example: what if one thread calls with '4', and then another calls with '4' a minute later - what *should* happen? Until you understand (and can explain) what *should* happen, it's hard to help you. Can each value only be printed once, ever? If so, what happens to the calling threads? Do they block forever?

Comment: @JVMATL when two threads calls with same value one should wait for other to finish. Simply stated if one thread is executing with value 4, all threads which are trying to execute with 4 should be blocked. But threads with other values than 4 should be allowed to access the syncronized method.so other threads with same values should wait until the current thread finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the requirement about preventing multiple threads from printing the same value, but allowing them print differing ones

The simplest way to prevent this is to have a set of Integers printed already.  Since you are printing the overhead of using a lock is trivial.

```
 Set<Integer> printed = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Integer>());

 // when printing
 if (printed.add(num)) // will one be true the first time for each number
     System.out.println("num: " + num);
```

> Can it be done?

Printing to the console is synchronized already and no matter what you do, all thread will synchorize their printing no matter what you do.  Adding more locking won't change that.

e.g. from PrintStream which implements System.out and err

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

You cannot simply decide to ignore the the `synchronized` here from the caller.

> Any provision for synchronizing on condition??

The simplest thing to do is to lock on a different lock or a thread local.  Locking an uncontented object is very quick.

e.g.

```
synchronized(shared ? sharedObject : Thread.currentThread()) {

}
```

BTW This is very strange/confusing thing to do.  I would seriously consider changing your design so this is not required.  Writing normal multi-threaded code is hard enough to write/understand.

Comment: I don't think this quite answers what he was asking (although the question is pretty vague, so I'm not 100% sure what was being asked..) -- how does this answer address the requirement about preventing multiple threads from printing the *same* value, but allowing them print differing ones? Despite the weird description, that sounds like and important part of the question..

Comment: @JVMATL you can't have multiple threads printing at the same time.  System.out is already synchronized, you can't unsynchronized it easily, nor would you want to.

Comment: I get that the System.out is synchronized, but from user's description, it's not clear that synchronizing on System.out to prevent printouts from interleaving is really the gist of his question; he seems to be asking how to do *something* differently if his method is called with 'the same value' vs if it is called with different values, and I'm just saying that this answer doesn't really address that. If all he cared about was preventing his prints from interleaving, then why would he even mention whether the values were the same or different? (and no, I can't figure out *what* he wants to do)

Comment: @JVMATL The second part of my answer is how to conditionally lock on a share object or not.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Let'say the function does not do print to the console.It does some other thing on that Integer.. as specified the important part of the question is "the requirement about preventing multiple threads from printing the same value, but allowing them print differing ones"..

Comment: @IshanBhatt Ok, added an answer to that question at the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Set<Integer> lockedIntegers = new HashSet<>();

private void lock(Integer key) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lockedIntegers) {
        while (!lockedIntegers.add(key)) {
            lockedIntegers.wait();
        }
    }
}

private void unlock(Integer key) {
    synchronized (lockedIntegers) {
        lockedIntegers.remove(key);
        lockedIntegers.notifyAll();
    }
}

public void printEqualIntegersSynchronously(Integer key) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        lock(key);

        System.out.println(key);
        //Do whatever you need with your key.
        //For different keys this part is executed in parallel.
        //For equal keys this part is executed synchronously.

    } finally {
        unlock(key);
    }
}
```

**try-finally** - is very important - you must guarantee to unlock waiting threads after your operation even if your operation threw exception. 'System.out.println' most probably will never throw exception - but for other real situations 'try-finally' is mandatory. And by the way 'System.out.println' is already synchronized by itself, so exactly for 'System.out.println' it is not needed.